# ASP.Net Register/Reference Nested Custom Control Class

Tags: asp.net

Ignoring the bad style, is it possible to include a page reference to a custom ASP.Net control that is a nested class?

My initial guess was...

Backing Class:

```
namespace Root.Namespace {
    public class OuterClass {
        public class InnerClass : Control {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<!-- ... -->
<%@ Register tagprefix="Prefix" namespace="Root.Namespace" %>
<!-- ... -->
<Prefix:OuterClass.InnerClass />
<!-- ... -->
```

However, that was throwing errors. Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx and the fact that a dot (.) in a tag name is not allowed, I am guessing that there is no way to reference an inner class via that method, but I am not sure.